# Add appsettings.json that contains Azure AD B2C info to source control

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-ad-b2c

With VS2017, when I create a web api project with "individual authentication" on Azure AD B2C, there is appsettings.json generated in the root directory and it contains the connection setting for the application registed in the B2C tenant.

Then, how can I keep this information secret when I publish this project to public repository like Github?

[This post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2017/09/10/managing-secrets-in-net-core-2-0-apps/) is referring somewhat related to the topic but I'm not sure if it's applicable for this case, since I'm not going to use the info to authenticate the users to use the api itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store the secrets in your appsettings.json at all. For development you could use the ASP.NET Core Secret manager (See [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows)). For your environments (e. g. production) you should either use the Azure Key Vault to access any secret / connection string or you overwrite the app settings within the portal.

Comment: So the post I attached is same here, right? And why the template generates the info in appsettings even though we shouldn't add the secret in the accessible directory?

Comment: I think the post is similar, yes. It probably generates these settings to ensure everything runs. Also if you have a private source control, it could be okay to check in development related connection strings (I don't say you should, it is usually bad).

Comment: I understood. Certainly letting it in visible location helpful for beginners to understand the app is packed completely and also works in come cases. Thanks for your suggestion.